# presheaves topoi - is it enough to prove that a functor preserves small colimits to get a left adjoint?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I have a certain functor $F:\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{O}(X)^{\mathsf{op}}}\rightarrow \mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{O}(Y)^{\mathsf{op}}}$, where $X,Y$ are topological spaces, and I want to prove that it is the inverse image of a geometric morphism. So I need to prove that $F$ has a right adjoint and that it preserves finite limits. 
In this discussion [Show that a functor which preserves colimits has a right adjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605480/show-that-a-functor-which-preserves-colimits-has-a-right-adjoint) it is proved that if a functor between presheaves topoi preserves colimits then it has a right adjoint. 
My question is: in my proof should I care only about preservation of *small* colimits?

Comment: Yes, that's what "preserves colimits" means. Most categories don't have most large colimits. Freyd famously showed that a category admitting all large colimits is a preorder: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complete+small+category#in_classical_logic